# Is it possible to force siunitx to output a decimal after the ones place?

Tags: siunitx

Conventional treatment of significant figures means that "60" has one significant figure and "60." has two significant figures. The decimal after the ones place implies that the ones-place digit is significant.

Currently, [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) does not handle this correctly, as is shown in the following MWE. The first three are rendered correctly, but the fourth is not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    % Two clearly-significant digits:
    % No decimal is necessary, but it is not incorrect to include it
    \SI{12}{\second}    % Should be "12 s" (two sig figs), but could be "12. s"
    \SI{12.}{\second}   % Could be either "12 s" OR "12. s",
                        %    because both digits are significant.
    
    % Clarifying an ambiguously-significant ones-place digit:
    \SI{60}{\second}    % Should be "60 s" (one significant figure)
    \SI{60.}{\second}   % Should be "60. s" (two significant figures),
                        %    but instead it produces "60 s"

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make `siunitx` handle this special case of significant figures properly? Short of that, is there a hack I could use to make it work correctly?

Comment: That's an interesting notational convention you cite. I must confess that I wasn't aware of it. Out of idle curiosity: What field of study do you work in? For me, both `60` and `60.` denote a number that was either an integer or a number that had been rounded to the nearest whole digit. (The underlying "true" number could be anywhere between 59.5 and 60.49999...) I'll admit to never having come across a situation where "60" could represent a number between 55 and 64.999...

Comment: In v2 I was a bit more laid back about data normalisation, but for v3 I've tried to tighten up. In particular, to me `60.` and `60` look the same, simply with the former written poorly, so they normalise to `60` internally. In particular, there is no information in `60.` or `12.345` about the number of _significant_ figures: one needs an e.s.d. for that. That said, I try to be as clear as I can that I don't make the 'rules', I just try to make as many options available as possible whilst setting the _standard_ values to be in my option 'clear'.

Comment: So what I would need here before considering a change is something from a publisher or similar showing that this approach is used in typeset material. Something similar has come up about writing probabilities as `.123` rather than `0.123` - whilst I don't like it very much, it's attested in the APA style guide so I will add it.

Comment: I have been canvassing opinion and seeking input on the use of this convention. I will examine support with one or two new options, but this may take a little while to develop. I will post an answer once I believe I have a workable approach.

Comment: @Mico "60" and "60." are numbers obtained from instruments/devices whose precisions are imperfect. The device that generates a value of "60" is less precise than the device that generates a value of "60."  "60" (w/o decimal) simply means the "0" is a placeholder and that device is not "good enough" to estimate the true digit that belongs in the ones place. "60." (w/ decimal) means the device used to make the measurement is "good enough" to estimate the digit that belongs in the ones place. The clearer way is to use scientific notation: 6×10^1 vs 6.0×10^1. But "60" and "60." is used, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be covered in v3.0.49 of `siunitx` with the option `retain-explicit-decimal-marker`. If you have an older v3 release and want to add as a patch, 'quick' edit (not covering everything) is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { siunitx }
  { retain-explicit-decimal-marker .bool_set:N = \l__siunitx_number_explicit_decimal_bool }
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_parse_loop_main_end:NN #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:NT \l__siunitx_number_partial_tl
      {
        \bool_if:NTF #2
          { \tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_number_partial_tl { 0 } }
          {
            \bool_if:NT \l__siunitx_number_explicit_decimal_bool
              { \tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_number_partial_tl { \empty } }
          }
      }
    \tl_put_right:Nx #1
      {
        { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_number_partial_tl }
        \bool_if:NT #2 { { } }
        { }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\num[retain-explicit-decimal-marker]{10.}
\end{document}
```

---

To explain why this is needed, in v2 I tracked integers and decimals separately internally. However, on reflection that felt artificial: physical quantities are floats, so that should be reflected in how the package works. I have never come across anyone using `10.` in professionally-typeset material, so this is a convention used in some areas I'm not familiar with. (That of course happens: writing a general units package I get requests for subject areas well outside my own academic experience.) So my starting point was to normalise the input: a lot of the numerical formatting code in `siunitx` is aimed at tables/automatically-generated values rather than one-offs. So to cover things here, I need to go back over some basic assumptions. That's of course possible, but it's non-trivial when you track through the data, as I've now got a documented and predicable API for it.

Comment: Fantastic! I really appreciate this! I can confirm that it works well in v3.0.49, and I'll be using it to write an exam right now. Thank you so much — not just for this feature, but also for all the work you put into `siunitx`. It's my favorite *TeX package, with the only possible tie being TikZ!